# Core-bluetooth - Is it possible to do a synchronous read?

Tags: objective-c, core-bluetooth

I'm building a IoT device and I have asynchronous reads working great, but I need to perform a synchronous read. I've been told this is possible on Android as there is a method that basically reads the buffer as it comes in.

I'm wondering if Core-bluetooth supports something similar or if anyone has a clever approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any asynchronous operation can be made synchronous by blocking until the operation completes.  You can use a queue or a lock to block.

```
NSLock *lock = [[NSLock alloc] init];
[thing doSomethingAsynchronousWithCompletion:^{
     [lock unlock];
 }];

 [lock lock];
```

**Do not do this.  Not ever.**

You shouldn't block.  Your asynchronous code's completion handler should trigger an event that causes your code to continue.

```
[thing doSomethingAsynchronousWithCompletion:^(NSData *readData){
     [dataProcessor processData:readData];
 }];
```